# How to use First() / FirstOrDefault()?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var flame = new string[]
        {
        "bad", "word"
        }

        ;
        var text = "this contains some bad words";
        foreach (string item in text.Split(' '))
        {
            bool testerino = flame.Any(item.Contains);
            if (testerino)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/as5iTs

I want `Console.WriteLine("1");` to run only once. I tried to use First() and FirstOrDefault() but I was not able to use it without syntax errors. Why I'm using a Split? I don't know. It was the only way to get `.Contains()` running. I did receive errors using `char item in text` with `Contains()`.

I don't need to use `foreach` or even `First()` it is just only way I know so far.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Try with `flame.Any(word => word == item)`

Comment: I want to receive Console.WriteLine("1"); only once. I don't think anyone would understand what I'm trying to do when I use the question "How to make Console.WriteLine("1"); only run once?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break after you act on the first match.

```
    foreach (string item in text.Split(' '))
    {
        bool testerino = flame.Any(item.Contains);
        if (testerino)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            break;
        }
    }
```

But a more concise alternative is just

```
if (test.Split(' ').Any(f=>flame.Contains(f))) Console.WriteLine("1");
```

If you are interested to see how `IEnumerable<T>.FirstOrDefault` could be used here, note that you can pass in a predicate to `FirstOrDefault` to get the first item in the `IEnumerable<T>` that matches that predicate (or the default value for `T` if nothing matches):

```
var firstMatch = test.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault(w=>flame.Contains(w));
if (firstMatch != null) Console.WriteLine("1");
```

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this:

```
var anyFlameWords = 
  text
  .Split(' ')
  .Any(word => flame.Contains(word));
if (anyFlameWords)
    Console.WriteLine("1");
```

You don't need First/FirstOrDefault, unless you want the first element from the collection, which looking at your existing code is not what you require.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `break;` to your if-case:

```
    foreach (string item in text.Split(' '))
    {
        bool testerino = flame.Any(item.Contains);
        if (testerino)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            break;
        }
    }
```

A `break` causes to exit the `foreach`-loop immediately.

Answer (score 1):

This linq may help

```
bool badWordExists = text.Split(' ').Any(s => flame.Contains(s));

if(badWordExists) Console.WriteLine("1");
```